# Deploying React App to Apache Server

Tags: apache, reactjs

I have a finished react app that works well on my localhost with `npm start`. 
I created the project with `create-react-app` and used the `npm run build` to compile a production website.

I have the whole folder with the `index.html` on my webspace. (They use an apache html server).

I managed to write an `.htaccess`file that loads the html correctly.  Now there is only a white screen. It seems like the `main.js` is not being loaded into the `root` div.

The only error I get in the console is that the service-worker could not be installed as my request comes not from a secure origin. This should not stop the rendering right?

I am not sure what files would be necessary to show here so please do let me know what you need to see to hopefully fix the problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Running **npm run build** command.

Copy and paste everything in ***build folder*** to your server.

Create a “.htaccess” file and add this snippet :

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

The application should work correctly.

Comment: I have done all that. It does not work I get on the site but there is nothing redered

Answer (score 1):

maybe its because you have ProxyPass in your conf file. you need to specific the homepage of your application.

`{
  "name": "application-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "homepage": "https://www.yourdomain.com/appliaction-context-path",
}`